pywin32 - win32com module not found
I tried to deploy a web service to azure portal (linux). However, my app service doesn't work and it stated "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'win32com'". I believe that win32com is not compatible for linux and exclusively only for windows.
I am working on these parameters:
from win32com import client as Client

outlook = Client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNameSpace("MAPI")
user_info = outlook.CreateRecipient(user).AddressEntry
office_location = user_info.GetExchangeUser().StateOrProvince
email_address = user_info.GetExchangeUser().PrimarySmtpAddress
manager_name = user_info.GetExchangeUser().GetExchangeUserManager().Name
manager_email = user_info.GetExchangeUser().GetExchangeUserManager().PrimarySmtpAddress

will appreciate your thoughts

COM, as it is, is a Windows only technology.

@SimonMourier, do you have any idea for workarounds/ alternatives?

I'm pretty sure it isn't even supported to automate Outlook on a Windows server under a service context (see Considerations for server-side Automation of Office).

AFAIK, Office desktop apps don't support Linux and Client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application") is using Outlook on the desktop, so I'm unsure what you're trying to do here.

This is potentially impossible for accessing MAPI of outlook directly with win32com.Especially with a linux service.. I don't know what your organization does but can just make a simple function for extracting responses with Outlook REST API.
-Not sure if it works.
import requests
import json

def get_user_info(access_token):
    """Fetches user information using the Outlook REST API.

    Args:
        access_token (str): The OAuth 2.0 access token.

    Returns:
        dict: A dictionary containing user information.
    """

    # Replace with the appropriate endpoint to get user details
    user_info_endpoint = "Your Outlook REST API Endpoint address"
    headers = {
        "Authorization": f"Bearer {access_token}"
    }

    response = requests.get(user_info_endpoint, headers=headers)

    if response.status_code == 200:  #Ensuring valid http response.
        user_data = json.loads(response.text)
        
        # Extract required information
        office_location = user_data.get("officeLocation", "")
        email_address = user_data.get("emailAddresses")[0].get("address", "")  # Assuming first email address
        manager = user_data.get("manager")
        manager_name = manager.get("displayName", "") if manager else ""
        manager_email = manager.get("emailAddress", {}).get("address", "") if manager else ""

        return {
            "office_location": office_location,
            "email_address": email_address,
            "manager_name": manager_name,
            "manager_email": manager_email
        }
    else:
        raise Exception(f"Error fetching user information: {response.text}")

